# How to set values for array elements inside the setState

Tags: reactjs

I have an array called `nextDayWeather` in state and i want to set values for that array elements inside the `setState`. I need to pass it to the component call `WeekTempretureControl` as I mention in the following code. please guide me. thank you.

```js
const API_KEY = "422edb157a5c2e7a35763933c19def46";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    nextDayWeather: [
      {
        id: 1,
        nextDayDate: new Date(),
        nextDayTempreture: 23.4,
        nextDayWeatherLabel: "rain"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        nextDayDate: new Date(),
        nextDayTempreture: 28.4,
        nextDayWeatherLabel: "clear sky"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        nextDayDate: new Date(),
        nextDayTempreture: 25.4,
        nextDayWeatherLabel: "broken clouds"
      }
    ]
  };

  getWeather = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const api_call = await fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city}&APPID=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
    );
    const data = await api_call.json();
    console.log(data);

    this.setState({
      //nextDayDate: new Date(),
      //nextDayTempreture: data.list[0].main.temp,
      //nextDayWeatherLabel: data.list[0].weather[0].description,
    });
  };

  render() {
    // let {currentLocation, currentDate, currentTempreture, currentWeatherLabel, currentWind, currentHumidity, currentPressure } = this.state.currentWeather;
    let { nextDayWeather } = this.state;

    return (
      <div id="bsec" className="b-color body-sec">
        <div className="main-wrapper">
          <WeekTempretureControl nextDayWeather={nextDayWeather} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 setState({...state, nextDayWeather: state.nextDayWeather.map( (day,index) => {
  if (index === THE_INDEX_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_TO_CHANGE) {
    return {
      id: index,
      nextDayDate: new Date(),
      nextDayTempreture: 5,
      nextDayWeatherLabel: "Rain"
    }
  }
  return {...day}

})})
```

First spread your state so anything you don't change will be carried over.

You take the next day array and map over it, spreading each object if it doesn't match your index, then on the index you want you can change it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

As state should be immutably updated, so 
first copy the state using clonedeep() from lodash or using spread operators,

then update the cloned object,

then set the state using updated data

```
getWeather = async e => {
e.preventDefault();
const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
const api_call = await fetch(
  `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city}&APPID=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
);
const data = await api_call.json();
console.log(data);
let updatedArray = clonedeep(this.state.nextDayWeather);
 updatedArray.forEach(item => {
   item.nextDayDate = new Date()
   item.nextDayTemp = data.list[0].main.temp
   item.nextDayWeatherLabel = data.list[0].weather[0].description
  })
 // so the piont is we use forEach/map/find/filter methods of array to update 
  all or some 
  // and if you want to update any one item inside the above array then any 
one of filter/map/... etc
  updatedArray.forEach(item => {
    if(item.id === 1){
      item.nextDayDate = new Date()
     item.nextDayTemp = data.list[0].main.temp
     item.nextDayWeatherLabel = data.list[0].weather[0].description
   }
  })
  // the above forEach loop will update only the item with id === 1, rest of 
  the 
  items will remain same

  this.setState({
    nextDayWeather:updatedArray
  });
};
```